# Oracle 11g - Exclude records from set where the hour column is greater than

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Consider the following, minimal example:

```
SQL> select key1, key2, key3, hour from teste_jm;

      KEY1       KEY2       KEY3 HOUR
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
        26  992296089       1504 12:30
        26  992296089       1275 13:30
```

I'd like to exclude the record where KEY3 is 1275, because its HOUR is greater than that of the record where KEY3 is 1504.

I tried the following, but to no success (I expected KEY4 to be 1504):

```
SQL> select key1, key2, key3, hour, min(key3) over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by to_date(hour, 'HH24:MI')) key4 from teste_jm;

      KEY1       KEY2       KEY3 HOUR        KEY4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----------
        26  992296089       1275 13:30       1275
        26  992296089       1504 12:30       1504
```

So essentially, what I'd like to do, in Oracle 11g, is to keep **only the records whose hour is the earliest**, for the same KEY1, KEY2 pair.

How would I do this?

EDIT: Here's a more complete example:

```
SQL> select * from teste_jm;

      KEY1       KEY2       KEY3 HOUR
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
        27  993334444          1 23:00
        27  993334444          2 23:59
        26  992296089       1504 12:30
        26  992296089       1275 13:30
```

Desired output for the above:

```
      KEY1       KEY2       KEY3 HOUR
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
        27  993334444          1 23:00
        26  992296089       1504 12:30
```

SQLFiddle containing the sample data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f31f/1/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you need a subquery to filter and the right logic for the minimum:

```
select key1, key2, key3, hour
from (select key1, key2, key3, hour,
             min(to_date(hour, 'HH24:MI')) over (partition by key1) as min_hour
      from teste_jm
     )  t
where hour = min_hour;
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you. Just a small correction: "hour" is a VARCHAR2(5) column in the HH24:MI format; therefore, the subquery should contain `to_date(hour, 'HH24:MI')` and `min(to_date(hour, 'HH24:MI'))` instead of `hour` and `min(hour)` respectively. Other than that, your answer seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just group by and get the min and I hope the above input vs o/p sample is correct so as to sync with below query

```
     Select  KEY1, KEY2 ,min(KEY3), HOUR 
     from table group by
          KEY1, KEY2
        having HOUR=min(HOUR)
```

Comment: That yields... ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: check now it should work. I just saw there were multiple key3's thats y it din work

Comment: Still doesn't work. Not a GROUP BY expression. I added an SQLFiddle link to my original post so you can check.

Answer (score -1):

try to do this

```
select key1, key2, key3, hour from teste_jm where hour = (select min(hour) from teste_jm);
```

Uh, after your edit, Try this

```
select key1, key2, key3, min(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY  key1,key2) from teste_jm;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't produce the output I want; see the "more complete example" above, where I want 2 records to be returned. I apologize for not being clearer sooner.

Comment: Hmm, your second answer is... Kinda close? I actually want to select some sort of MIN(KEY3) instead of MIN(HOUR)... Except... In order to decide what the minimum value is, I want the HOUR column to be used. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You just have to have a condition in having clause as those keys of min hour check my answer